# The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Tags: php, fastcgi

I have fast cgi installed on my iis, and i get this when debugging php site,
I already set the php ini to have a long timeput, where is the fast cgi config? what to change?

Answer (score 0):

The FastCGI timeout has nothing to do with PHP's internal execution time limit - it's the time the web server process waits for the CGI process to finish its output. On Apache, it'd be the `idle-timeout` setting:

```
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.3.1 -idle-timeout 120
```

Maybe there is something similar for IIS.